# DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories() not working when run in Admin mode

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console

There is no end to surprises, it seems. I am trying to enumerate directories of a folder:

```
const string PATH = @"c:\temp";
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(PATH);

var subs = dir.EnumerateDirectories(); // <= This fails

foreach (var sub in subs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sub.Name);
}
```

This code runs fine, except when executed with Administrator privileges ("Run As Administrator"), in which case it fails, with an exception

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path ...

The path exists, contains no hidden or system files, and - as I said - the app runs in user mode, but not in administrator mode, which is very surprising...

Comment: Did you check what `PATH` is when run as admin? If you run as admin, the executable might be run at system folder. If you're using relative path, `PATH` might go wrong.

Comment: @Louis Go The path is absolute. and exactly the same in both cases (like `c:\temp`). Regardless of whether I am executing it in Visul Studio or from the command line, the effect is always the same: Admin fails, normal user works. The same issue occurs with the full .NET Framework, so it's not specific to .NET Core.

Comment: Since you've obviously already tried to just run CMD "as admin" with the same path please [edit] post to share results. Also  output of "cacls c:\temp" may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it will look strange, I had faced similar issue and it may sound really silly, but restarting my machine had worked for me.

Comment: Indeed - sometimes files/folders are locked by current account but considered "deleted" (remove on restart) for other accounts...

Comment: @Ash LOL. Indeed. Sometimes the simplest solutions are the hardest to find.